# What is the proper way to handle an incorrect directory path taken as user input?

Tags: python, path, user-input

Below is a snippet of code I am trying to use to take a directory path as "raw input" from the user. I receive the following error after the input is taken from the user:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\larece.johnson\Desktop\Python Programs\Hello World 2", line 14, in <module>
    f = open(path, "r+")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/larece.johnson/Desktop/Python Programs/BostonLog.log.2014-04-01'
```

Notice that the `.log` file ending is missing from the user input.

For example, the directory and file I'm looking for is

```
C:/Users/larece.johnson/Desktop/Python Programs/BostonLog.log.2014-04-01.log
```

But the user entered

```
C:/Users/larece.johnson/Desktop/Python Programs/BostonLog.log.2014-04-01
```

Is there a particular way I am supposed to take the path from user so that Python accepts it?

This was my original code:

```
#f = open("C:/Users/larece.johnson/Desktop/BostonLog.log.2014-04-02.log", "r+")

# User will enter the name of text file for me
path = raw_input("Enter the name of your text file: ")
f = open(path, "r+")
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you should try something like:

```py
from pathlib import Path

user_input = Path(input("Enter the path of your file: "))
 
if not user_input.exists():
    raise ValueError(f"I did not find the file at {user_input}")
with open(user_input, "r+") as iof:
    print("Hooray we found your file!")
    #stuff you do with the file goes here
```

Comment: @mkrieger1, I got rid of the `assert`

Answer (score 6):

It seems you want to check if the directory exists.

If so, see [os.path.isdir](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir).

```
os.path.isdir(path)
    Return True if path is an existing directory.
    This follows symbolic links, so both islink()
    and isdir() can be true for the same path.
```

You can do like this:

```
s = raw_input();
if os.path.isdir(s):
    f = open(s, "r+")
else:
    print "Directory not exists."
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out... I forgot to add the file extension at the end of the file name on my directory path; I did not notice that I was cutting it off by just copying/pasting the name of my file.... the program works now... thank you all!