# How to account for special characters in windows file paths - python

Tags: python, windows, filesystems

I am trying to create a script that goes through windows files and removes "." form the file name with the path entered as a string. The problem starts when any folder in the path starts with a  `a`, `b`, `e`, `f`, `n`, `r`, `s`, `t`, `v` or `x` (Backslash Notation in python). Then the system throws a fit saying this is not a valid path (specifically with the error message below). A workaround is to use `"/"` in the path and run `os.path.normpath(folder)` But I cant seem to find a way to pick up all the `\` to switch them at runtime (python ignores ones with the above list of characters after them so round and round we go).

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Mendel\OneDrive\Code\Python - 2\fileNameCleanUp.py", line 39, in <module>
rename(test_folder)
File "C:\Users\Mendel\OneDrive\Code\Python - 2\fileNameCleanUp.py", line 21, in rename
for filename in os.listdir(folder):             #for every file in the folder
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\Mendel\\Desktop\rmdot\\*.*'
```

**EDIT 1**
Code:

```
import sys, os


def rename(folder):
    //folder = os.path.normpath(folder)
    print "Folder: = ", folder
    if not folder.endswith('\\'):       #Check for windows path divider at the end
        if folder.find('\\') > 0:       #Check if it is windows
            folder += '\\'              #Add path divider to the end

    print "Folder: = ", folder
    #Rename files
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):             #for every file in the folder
        infilepath = os.path.join(folder, filename) #make a path out of it
        if os.path.isfile(infilepath) == False:     #Check if it is valid
            continue                                #if not: next file

        nameParts = filename.split(".")
        print "\nNew File:"
        print "nameParts: ", nameParts
        print "Length: ", len(nameParts)
        print "Length - 1: ", nameParts[len(nameParts) - 1]


test_folder = "C:/Users/Mendel/Desktop/rmdot"
rename(test_folder_2)
```

**TL;DR**: How do I account for backslash notation in windows paths entered as strings using python?

Thanks,

Comment: It's really unclear. Can you post your code?

Comment: Can you please post the full errors ?

Comment: If it helps. All it says is it crashes on trying to read the path.

Comment: You have to use double backslash to explicit the fact that the backslash is not for a special character `"C:\\Users\\Mendel\\Desktop\\rmdot"`, you can also use the `r` prefix for your string `r"c:\Users\Mendel\Desktop\rmdot"`

Comment: Have you tried [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals): `listdir(r'c:\new')` is ok.

Comment: The use case is automated where I am pulling the paths on the fly. I tried string.replace("\", "\\") but it does nothing. @robyschek Yes and it works but i can't make inputted strings raw

Comment: This post explains how to get raw strings from input using `raw_input` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939211/what-is-the-proper-way-to-take-take-a-directory-path-as-user-input

Comment: @robyschek please explain in answer

Comment: it's really unclear to me, what's the origin of your path ? Is it really the code that you posted which fails ?

Comment: Yes. The origin of the path is coming from several places. the code above has it as a hardcoded string representing what is generally fed into the function

Comment: Maybe you can print the path just before the call to `listdir`. Honestly i tried on my own and it works fine if the path is correctly encoded when it's collected.

Comment: If the path has control characters in it, you need to fix it at the source -- not after the fact. The problem is maybe bad data in a file or maybe it's from evaluating a string literal (i.e. syntax that Python's compiler uses to create a string object -- not just data read as a string object).